# Problems with Alamofire and Swift closures

Tags: swiftui, closures, alamofire

I have the following class with a function that returns a boolean value using alamofire.

```
class Productos: Codable{
    
    // MARK: Propiedades de los productos
    var id_producto : String = ""
    var producto_es : String = ""
    var id_seccion : String = ""
   
    init(id_producto : String = "", producto_es : String = "", id_seccion : String = ""){
        self.id_producto = id_producto
        self.producto_es = producto_es
        self.id_seccion = id_seccion
    }

    func hayProductosNuevos(ultimoProductoEnBd: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let urlWS = Globales().urlWS//Url para la webservice
      
        AF.request(urlWS+"actualiza_productos.php?ultimo_producto=\(ultimoProductoEnBd)",method: .get).responseDecodable(of: [Productos].self) { responseConsulta in
            switch responseConsulta.result{
                case .success(let actualizacionDeProductos):
                    if (actualizacionDeProductos.isEmpty){
                        completion(false)
                    } else {
                        completion(true)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("hay un error \(String(describing: error.errorDescription))")
            }
         }
    }
}
```

My problem is how to call it and control what is returned to me from my view:

[image]

I know that within a view I cannot call it that. The idea is if I return true, perform a product update and display a ProgressView.

I have tried everything I have been reading, using its init() in the view. But I get another error.

[image]

**I think my problem is that from Alamofire I need to know if I have to update my application's data or not, that's why it returns true or false, but I'm not clear about the use of closures, so I don't know how I have to call Alamofire from my view so I can control the data.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is wrong, you cannot put the ***model*** which is used in an array   containing multiple instances and the ***controller*** to load the data in the same object. Well actually you can do it but then you have to create **static** APIs which is bad practice though.

First of all declare the object representing a product as struct named in singular form and without the logic to load the data.

```
struct Producto: Decodable {
    
    // MARK: Propiedades de los productos
    var id_producto : String 
    var producto_es : String
    var id_seccion : String
}
```

And it's highly recommended to use *camelCase* struct member names, but this is beyond the question. And if the values will never change declare the struct members as constants (`let`).

---

Then create a class conforming to `ObservableObject` for the logic to load the data with a `@Published` property for the products and a method to load the data. A completion handler is not needed, assign (or append) the result to the array. Actually AF is not needed either for a simple GET request, built-in `URLSession` and `JSONDecoder` can do the same.

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var productos = [Producto]()

    func hayProductosNuevos(ultimoProductoEnBd: Int) {
        let urlWS = Globales().urlWS //Url para la webservice
      
        AF.request(urlWS+"actualiza_productos.php?ultimo_producto=\(ultimoProductoEnBd)",method: .get).responseDecodable(of: [Producto].self) { responseConsulta in
            switch responseConsulta.result {
                case .success(let actualizacionDeProductos):
                    self.productos = actualizacionDeProductos
                    // or self.productos.append(contentsOf: actualizacionDeProductos)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("hay un error", error)
            }
         }
    }
}
```

---

In the view create an instance of `ViewModel` as `@StateObject` and load the data in `onAppear`

```
struct ActualizarProductos : View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var ultimoProductoEnBd = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
          // UI stuff
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.hayProductosNuevos(ultimoProductoEnBd: ultimoProductoEnBd)
        }
    }
}
```

The `ultimoProductoEnBd` is not handled in the question, it's just an example adding a `@State` property.

Comment: Great solution, thank you very much. I come from programming in android with Kotlin, and I'm converting my application to SwiftUI and it's getting a bit difficult for me.

Thank you